# mPDF temporary file is not writable using Yii

Tags: php, yii, mpdf

I tried to print a certificate in PDF but when I push my code to staging, it said

```
Temporary files directory "/var/www/protected/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp" is not writable
```

I'm not sure how to change the permission and how to change the custom directory.

Here's my code of a button to click to get the certificate:

```
 <a class="btn btn-sd btn-sd-ghost btn-sd-ghost-black margin-right-lg" href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/pdf', array('id'=>$model->id))?>" target="_blank">Get Your Certificate<i class="icon-right-small"></i></a> 
            <?php endif; ?>
```

and this is the controller:

```
public function actionPdf($id){
        $model = HUB::getOrganization($id);
        $orgtitle = $model->title;

        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4-L']);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML("<html><body style='background-image:url(\"/images/cert-idea.jpg\"); background-image-resize: 5; background-position: top center;'></body></html>");

        $mpdf->WriteHTML("<div style='text-align:center; display:table; height:100%; width:100%; padding-top:28%;'><h1 style='display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; font-size:40px;'>".$orgtitle."</h1></div>");


        $mpdf->Output('IDEA-CERT-'.$orgtitle.'.pdf', 'I');
    }
```

Hope someone can help on my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using yii1 or yii2? Are you using [Kartik's mPDF extension](http://demos.krajee.com/mpdf)? Did you set any of the configuration options in `app/config/web`?

Comment: SOLUTION: I'm using this way

`$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4-L', 'tempDir'=>Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.runtime')]);
`

Comment: Your solution looks very similar to @Finwe's answer. If that is what helped you solve the problem you could mark his answer as accepted, otherwise write your own answer and accept it (you will need to wait 48 hours)

Answer (score 17):

Try a custom temporary directory as stated in [the documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html):

> It is recommended to set custom temporary directory via `tempDir` configuration key. The directory must have write permissions (mode 775 is recommended).

```
<?php
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/custom/temp/dir/path']);
```

You will have far more control over permissions of a directory outside composer vendor-dir.

Mode 775 may not be sufficient if a web-server user, typically `www-data` has to access the directory. Use 777 if necessary.

Be warned that mPDF auto-cleans its temporary directory, so use one dedicated only to mPDF.

Answer (score 11):

You can change the file permission with:
`chmod 777 /var/www/protected/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp`
but that would allow **anyone** on that computer **any** type of access to that file, so probably not a good idea. It would give you  a starting point though, if this works you know that the problem is file permissions.

You may need to run it as super-user if you are not the owner of that file

A better solution would be to change the owner to be the process that the server runs on,
`chown www-data: /var/www/protected/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp`
changing `www-data` for the process that will save the file.

It is strange that is trying to save the pdf to that directory though, are you using Kartik's mPDF? The default configuration is to send the file inline to the browser, it should only be trying to save the file if you changed the configuration, either globally or when you create the widget, to:

```
'destination' => ['Pdf::DEST_FILE', '../../tmp']
```

If that is the case then the best would be to configure that to whichever option you need, probably `Pdf::DEST_BROWSER` (default) or `Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD` to force a download without prompting the user.

Saving the pdf as a file inside the directory where the application is doesn't really make sense unless you only ever plan to use your developing computer as a client, there is no way to tell what other client's folder structures will look like so it is much better to let their browsers decide what to do with the file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I found the way by using this

`$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4-L', 'tempDir'=>Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.runtime')]);
`

Answer (score 9):

It is essential to provide writable temporary directory. Best solution is to use OS provided temporary space.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => sys_get_temp_dir().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mpdf']);
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to your project `root` path(where the `vendor` folder exists).
and run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp
```

Comment: Getting sane error not working after changing permission

Answer (score 1):

Use php tmp with try

```
        try {
        $mpdf = new Mpdf([
            'tempDir' => '/tmp', // uses tmp to store PDF
        ]);
      } catch (\Mpdf\MpdfException $e) {
            // Return 500 if mPDF fails to create instance 
            $response->setMessage("Creating an mPDF object failed with" . $e->getMessage());
            $response->setStatusCode(500);
            return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to provide full permission of 777 to a particular folder.

path: `vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config`
change path in the below variable(`tempDir`) :

```
 'tempDir' => '/var/log/',
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for (XAMPP / LAMPP Ubuntu)

- open terminal then set as super user (su)
- copy and paste bellow from sudo-tmp

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan21/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp
```

```
sudo chown -R sahrulsidik /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan21/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp
```

Comment: Please explain what your suggested commands are meant to do, and how they might fix the OP's problem.

Comment: Never, never, unless you know what are you doing, give a folder 777 permissions.